# Removing the HTML from my function

Tags: jquery, json, each

working with JSON, I have successfully retrieved the results as an object. After a lot of struggle I have managed to get it to work. However, I would greatly appreciate any help to 'clean' the solution, as I have read that as best practice you should always keep your HTML and jQuery seperate.

The snippet of code can be found at the link below:

http://jsfiddle.net/xunZU/

```
var results = $.map(data.GSP.RES.R, function (result) {
    return {
        title: result.T,
        snippet: result.S,
        url: result.U
    };

}); //var results

$.each(results, function (index, obj) {
    $('#results_holder').append('<h2><a href="' + obj.url + '">' + obj.title + '</a></h2>' + '<p>' + obj.snippet + '</p>');
}); //each
```

Comment: There's not much point in a jsfiddle that doesn't work. In any case, this is more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: if you are not going to append html using jquery,all your h2 and p elements should be there already and you have to change their attributes and inner html using jquery.your current sol is better than that

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys, all great advice, I have marked my 'answer' as the one that I implemented. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seperating JS from HTML, CSS from HTML etc. is a good idea, as it stays true to the practice of separating function, style and form etc.

On the other hand there is nothing wrong with creating a few elements with javascript every now and then, and to clean it up I would do :

```
var results = $.map(data.GSP.RES.R, function (result) {
    return {
        title  : result.T,
        snippet: result.S,
        url    : result.U
    };
});

$.each(results, function (index, obj) {
    var h2 = $('<h2 />'),
        a  = $('<a />', {text: obj.title, href: obj.url}),
        p  = $('<p />', {text: obj.snippet});

    $('#results_holder').append( h2.append(a), p );
});
```

as `$.each` also works with objects, the `$.map` is'nt really neccessary, and you could also do:

```
$.each(data.GSP.RES.R, function (index, obj) {
    var h2 = $('<h2 />'),
        a  = $('<a />', {text: obj.T, href: obj.U}),
        p  = $('<p />', {text: obj.S});

    $('#results_holder').append( h2.append(a), p );
});
```

Comment: Great, I had a feeling I was doubling up with the .map and .each

Answer (score 2):

If you do this kind of thing often, I've found the use of a templating libraries to be very helpful. Personally use handlebars.js. Makes it pretty simple to seperate markup from your javascript.

http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: Hey, yeah I looked into implementing handlebars, but was asked to not call too many additional libraries unless absolutely essential. Thanks for the recommendation

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can roll your own pseudo-templating engine like this: http://jsfiddle.net/joeframbach/xunZU/1/

By adding a hidden template:

```
<div id="templates" style="display:none;">
<h2><a></a></h2><p></p>
</div>

<div id="results_holder"></div>
```

And cloning it:

```
var data = [
    {T: 'foo1', S: 'bar1', U: 'bat1'},
    {T: 'foo2', S: 'bar2', U: 'bat2'},
    {T: 'foo3', S: 'bar3', U: 'bat3'},
    {T: 'foo4', S: 'bar4', U: 'bat4'},
    {T: 'foo5', S: 'bar5', U: 'bat5'},
]
var results = $.map(data, function (result) {
    return {
        title: result.T,
        snippet: result.S,
        url: result.U
    };

}); //var results

$.each(results, function (index, obj) {
    var tpl_h2 = $('#templates h2').clone();
    var tpl_p = $('#templates p').clone();
    tpl_h2.find('a').attr('href',obj.url).html(obj.title);
    tpl_p.html(obj.snippet);
    $('#results_holder').append(tpl_h2).append(tpl_p);
}); //each
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, I was using a pseudo template, however, on resubmission of a search I called an .empty() on the div and it removed the template aswell so, due to my limited knowledge, I tried to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for a 'clean' solution for DOM manipulation. Clean is a relative term. I would think that you just want something that is maintainable. Juggling HTML and Javascript can get cumbersome if they fall out of sync. I don't believe that there is a single *correct* answer, but you can surely find something that suits you or your teams needs.

I was going to suggest a .clone() just as joeframbach suggested, but I would instead use the entire DOM element and some subclasses rather than copying the elements individually. Then there is no need to have any knowledge of the underlying elements or structure.

Here's my branch of his fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/krets/sESy2/2/

```
$.each(results, function (index, obj) {
    var tpl = $('#templates').clone();
    tpl.attr('id','unique'+index)
    tpl.find('.linkOne').attr('href',obj.url).html(obj.title);
    tpl.find('.one').html('unique'+index);
    tpl.find('.two').html(obj.snippet);
    tpl.removeClass('hidden')
    $('#results_holder').append(tpl);
}); //each
```